# MySQL INNER JOIN query to get client information having at least 10 rentals

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to query the code, name, and the number of rentals of customers who have made at least ten rentals.

My query:

```
Select client.ClientCode, client.ClientNom, (location.LocationRef)
FROM client
  INNER JOIN location ON client.ClientCode = location.ClientCode
WHERE location.LocationRef > 9
GROUP BY location.ClientCode;
```

Output:

```
ClientCode | ClientNom | LocationRef
-----------+-----------+------------
12874      | Alex      | 10
```

It doesn't work. It shows me the first `LocationRef` beyond 10 but not the number of rentals made by the client.

I test with a `COUNT` in my query :

```
SELECT client.ClientCode, client.ClientNom, Count(location.LocationRef) 
  FROM client 
    INNER JOIN location 
      ON client.ClientCode = location.ClientCode WHERE location.LocationRef > 9 
GROUP BY location.ClientCode;
```

This is what i got :

```
ClientCode | ClientNom | Count(location.locationRef)
-----------+-----------+----------------------------
12874      | Alex      | 5
```

This is not what I want, because my client has made 13 rentals and it only shows me the number of rentals beyond the 9th rental.

Script to install my database:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;

SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `ClientCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ClientNom` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `client` (`ClientCode`, `ClientNom`) VALUES
(123, 'Gaetan'),
(12874, 'Alex'),
(12875, 'Max');

CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `LocationRef` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Immatriculation` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `ClientCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MontantLocation` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `location` (`LocationRef`, `Immatriculation`, `ClientCode`, `MontantLocation`) VALUES
(1, 'AA-229-AA', 12874, 123), (2, 'AA-229-AB', 12875, 156),
(3, 'BA-229-AA', 12874, 700), (4, 'AB-229-AA', 12874, 678),
(5, 'AA-229-AB', 12874, 987), (6, 'AA-229-AB', 12874, 980),
(7, 'AB-229-AA', 12874, 567), (8, 'AA-229-AA', 12874, 7789),
(9, 'AA-229-AB', 12874, 567), (10, 'AA-229-AB', 12874, 456),
(11, 'AA-229-AA', 12874, 566), (12, 'AB-229-AA', 12874, 700),
(13, 'AA-229-AA', 12874, 899), (14, 'AA-229-AB', 12874, 67);
```

Comment: When your task says "*number*" it's very likely that you will need to have `COUNT(...)` in your queue.

Comment: Yes but when I put a COUNT in my query it's also not the result I want

Comment: What is the result you get that isn't what you want? We need to know specifics.

Comment: I posted the result that it puts me and which does not suit me

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: You haven't posted a result. PS A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query condition `WHERE location.LocationRef > 9` is not doing what you expect. It's limiting your query to only access the 10th and later entries into the `location` table. Entries where `LocationRef` equals  1 - 9 are ignored.

And `Count(location.LocationRef)` is in the wrong part of the query.

---

Rather, put the [`COUNT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) and [`GROUP BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) in an ad hoc, temporary table querying the `location` table, [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)'ed with the `client` table, to get client information and count how many records there are over a certain number of client records, then limit the querying of client information to only those who have at least 10 entries:

```
SELECT loc.ClientCode, loc.cnt, client.ClientNom 
  FROM client 
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ClientCode, COUNT(ClientCode) cnt 
        FROM location 
        GROUP BY clientCode
    ) loc ON client.ClientCode = loc.ClientCode
  WHERE loc.cnt > 9 /* at least 10 entries */
;
```

Output:

```
ClientCode | cnt | ClientNom
-----------+-----+----------
12874      | 13  | Alex
```

---

The temporary table query:

```
SELECT ClientCode, COUNT(ClientCode) cnt 
  FROM location 
  GROUP BY clientCode
```

...uses a combination of [`COUNT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) AND [`GROUP BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) to determine how many records there are for each `ClientCode`.

And results in the output:

```
ClientCode | cnt
-----------+----
12874      | 13
12875      | 1
```

Now this becomes the temporary table that can be `INNER JOIN`'ed with the `client` table, using the `ClientCode` field, to get the client information: `ON client.ClientCode = loc.ClientCode`.

Also the calculated field `COUNT(ClientCode)`, in the temp table query, is aliased `cnt` for access outside the temp table query, as in: `loc.cnt` and `WHERE loc.cnt > 9`.

The temporary table must be named. That name is then used to access it's values outside of the temporary table query itself:

```
INNER JOIN ( /* temp query here */ ) loc ON client.ClientCode = loc.ClientCode
```

In this case using the name `loc` and referencing fields like this: `loc.ClientCode`.

And, finally, it's the primary query, or outside query, where the results are limited to only those clients with a count (`cnt`) of more than 9 (at least 10) entries in the `loc` table:

```
SELECT loc.ClientCode, loc.cnt, client.ClientNom
  FROM client
  /* INNER JOIN here, named loc */
WHERE loc.cnt > 9
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yfwuunrs

Answer (score 0):

Start with a subquery to find all the ClientCode values that have ten or more items in your `location` table. The aggregating subquery does the counting.

```sql
                SELECT ClientCode
                  FROM location
                 GROUP BY ClientCode
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

Then INNER JOIN that subquery in your main query to filter out all but the frequent customers.

```sql
SELECT client.ClientCode, client.ClientNom, (location.LocationRef)
  FROM client
 INNER JOIN location ON client.ClientCode = location.ClientCode
 INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT ClientCode
                   FROM location
                  GROUP BY ClientCode
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
) frequent_clients  ON client.ClientCode = frequent_clients.ClientCode;
```

If you want just one row per client in your result set, try this

```sql
SELECT client.ClientCode, client.ClientNom, COUNT(*) number_of_rentals
  FROM client
 INNER JOIN location ON client.ClientCode = location.ClientCode
 INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT ClientCode
                   FROM location
                  GROUP BY ClientCode
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
    ) frequent_clients
          ON client.ClientCode = frequent_clients.ClientCode
GROUP BY client.ClientCode, client.ClientNom
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6BzmQ2PQ).

Comment: Ok !! this is what i want thanks you very much, but i want them appear in one table and not one table for one rental, i just want that the "LocationRef " contains the number of rentals my client made (to be clear)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. For best results edit your question to show a sample of the output you require.